# How is the authorization-string of IBM COS created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I am trying to figure out how exactly is the authorization-string for IBM Cloud object storage created. I do have an accessKeyId and accessKeySecret.

I am able to connect to the bucket using cyberDuck. But need to manage the objects using Java and Rest APIs.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the signature generation sample for java(and others) here : https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/hmac/hmac-signature.html#java-example

Additional info : S3 admin can set the authorization from AWS Signature to a BASE64 auth as well.